# Adding values from wide data frame to long data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple data frames that are either wide format or long format, and I'm trying for set up a generic piece of code (loop or other) that will allow me to take values from the wide df and insert them into the long df.

See attached for screenshots of the two data frames.

[image: long DF image]
[image: wide DF image]

I'd like to get the scan date for each scan in the wide DF into a new variable in the long DF. Feels simple, but I'm stuck - thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
datalong <- gather(datawide, -PID)
datalong$ScanType <- ifelse(str_detect(as.character(datalong$key), "date"), "scan_date","scan_name")
datalong <- spread(datalong, ScanType, value)
#Merge with other long dataframe
NewLong <- merge(oldLong, datalong, by = c("PID","scan_name")
```

I believe this will work, but I cant be sure because there isn't a reproducible example. You will end up with an extra column most likely named "key" which is from `gather(datawide, -PID)`. If you dont want this extra bit of metadata you can subset that column out of datalong before you execute the `spread(data, ScaneType, value)` line.